# How to only allow specific users to edit certain "fields" when creating content?

Tags: 7, users

I want to be able to hide specific fields form users on the create content form. For example, I might let any authenticated user create an article but only the editors can use the upload a picture field and the category field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Field Permission Module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions). This will provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, the only problem is that it's in beta for D7, I just need to be really careful with it because this will be used on a site going live soon. Thanks.